# How to create turtles of a particular breed in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I want with pressing the  setup button at the netlogo  tree and  house shapes exist But only 3 person  show to me Please help me:

```
    breed [people person]
      breed [houses house]
      breed [trees   tree]
            to setup
        clear-all
        set-default-shape people "person"
        set-default-shape houses  "house"
            set-default-shape trees   "tree"
     crt 3[         
      set color red
      set size 2  ;; easier to see
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
     ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `create-houses` (instead of `crt`) to create houses. See [create-turtles](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/create-turtles.html) in manual.